# How to replace the party's face?

Tags: social, party

I am GMing a game of modern exploration/mystery with some combat. The group is tiny (GM+3 players), but that is not a problem for me as selected game (Mage:Ascension from owod) supports smaller parties and puts more limelight for everyone to enjoy. However one of the players decided to quit the game due to outside world reasons (or giving that excuse, which I accept with no hard feelings).

The party started as three players and characters:

- **The face**. Character was a socialite that usually took lead to carry conversations and push agenda forward. This is the player that left, but he was only moderately invested in the game, my assumption due to being sincerely busy and the game being a bit too taxing/complex.
- **The dragon**. This character often acted as a supporting face. The player invested in the character development and liked roleplaying emotions of the PC. He would enjoy a challenge and a puzzle or combat.
- **The voice from the back**. This character "hangs out". The player is quite laid back, not too invested and prefers to play his character "as needed" being an asset to the party but not dominating the play. He would activate when a clear goal is being established, while not being too decisive over how the goal should be approached.

Now there is a GM + 2 PC group. We will look for a 3rd player, but for a while we will play like that.

I would like advice on how to aid my players to establish either equally-active partnership or a party face with the other player being an advisor. I'm fine with a situation where the mellow player activates a bit to form a pair of partners with equal say. However, I am concerned that he won't do that, preferring to remain as advisor/first officer, and the other player will not like his newly acquired leading role. We haven't played the game yet, so I do not know what is going to happen, but I would like to ease that tension and help them quickly settle in the new arrangement, whatever that might be, as long as they are happy with the outcome.

Comment: I think a system tag is going to be needed for you to get real answers, maybe even a setting tag. How important a "party face" is or what that term exactly means varies from system to system and setting to setting.

Comment: I have mentioned the system in the body of the question for that exact reason, but I would see that as a social issue first and foremost. I feel quite confident about my ability to steer the system and the setting to accommodate for just two players.

Comment: This is less about your abilities as a GM and more about getting helpful and on point answers.

Comment: I'm unclear on which of the two problems this is about, and what the problem with it is. Is the problem how to get the quiet player to be more active, or is it how to find a new player? Which one are you concerned will cause "grinding gears"? And, if you please, could you replace that metaphor and tell us what you're concerned about happening?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Did my best to clarify - rewrote the last paragraph completely.

Comment: It sounds less like the problem is that nobody would want to step up and be the Face, and more that… something… is wrong with not having one. What is that something? Is it that there won't be a proactive player? Or that lacking social-focused skills will be a mechanical problem? Something else? Why do you think someone need to step up and become the new Face?

Comment: As I said, I'm happy if they become equal partners with equal say, participating in conversations etc. equally. I'm afraid that it won't happen or that the "leading" player will not enjoy his new role.

Comment: It sounds like the face was just the party PR, and someone who did some of the talking. Is there anything actually providing resistance or an obstacle to other players stepping into this role? Is there a complication in someone just adopting it and doing the party PR? I'm clear on what your situation is (I think), but unclear on what problem you think might be present that you need our help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've already answered your own question.

You say the Dragon has already been acting as a supporting face, so there's no reason to assume he can't/won't continue to do so.  He wouldn't have been doing it if he didn't mind.

Comment: Well, thanks for that input. I'll see what happens during the session and post results. If I still have a problem, I'll try to reopen the question.